# Homomorphis from $\mathbb{Z_{36}}$ to a group of order $24$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

> Suppose that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ to a group of order $24$. Find all homomorphic images and for each images determine $\ker(\phi)$.

*$\underline{\text{Solution:}}$*

We know homomorphism completely determined by the generators of domain.

$\underline{\text{Possible orders for }\phi(1):}$

$1\in\mathbb{Z}_{36}$, $\vert 1 \vert=36$. Also we know in a homomorphism $\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))\vert \mathrm{o}(1)=36$, so $\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))\vert 36$. And by Lagrange Theorem, $\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))\vert 24$. Hence, $$\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=1,2,3,4,6,12$$

We know give a property of group homomorphism:

$$\text{Let G be a group, H be a subgroup of G and } \phi \text{ be a homomorphism. If H is cyclic then } \phi(H) \text{ also cyclic.}$$
$$\text{Every finite cyclic group with order n is isomorphic to the integers modulo n}$$

$\underline{\text{Structure of } \phi(1):}$

Using this theorem since $\langle 1 \rangle < \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ we know $\langle\phi(1)\rangle$ is cyclic. So we can write:

$$\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=1, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e \rbrace \cong {e}\\
\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=2, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e, a \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \\
\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=3, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e,a,a^2 \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3} \\
\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=4, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e,a,a^2,a^3 \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4}\\
\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=6, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e,a,a^2,...,a^5 \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6}\\
\mathrm{o}(\phi(1))=12, \; \phi(1)=\lbrace e,a,a^2,a^3,...,a^{11} \rbrace \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}\\$$

Now, we investigate for each groups we need to find kernels:

$\underline{\text{Finding kernels to the corresponding images}:}$

We know $\ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ we will use this.

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=3 \text{ and} \\ \ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{3}\right\rangle=\langle 12\rangle =\lbrace 0,12,24 \rbrace$$

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6}:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=6 \text{ and} \\ \ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{6}\right\rangle=\langle 6\rangle =\lbrace 0,6,12,18,24,30 \rbrace$$

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4}:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=9 \text{ and} \\ \ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{9}\right\rangle=\langle 4\rangle =\lbrace 0,4,8,12,...,32 \rbrace$$

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=12 \text{ and} \\ \ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{12}\right\rangle=\langle 3\rangle =\lbrace 0,3,6,9,12,...,33 \rbrace$$

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{Ker(\phi)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=18 \text{ and} \\ \ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{18}\right\rangle=\langle 2\rangle =\lbrace 0,2,4,...,34 \rbrace$$

$\underline{\text{For } \phi(1) \cong \lbrace e \rbrace:}$

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{36}}{\ker(\phi)} \cong \lbrace e \rbrace \rightarrow \mathrm{o}(\ker(\phi))=36 \text{ and} \\\ker(\phi) < \mathbb{Z}_{36}, \; \left\langle \frac{36}{36}\right\rangle=\langle 1\rangle =\lbrace 0,1,2,...,35 \rbrace$$

Are there any mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1. This is delightfully well formatted. You can clean up the "Kers" though... I'll do that now!

Comment: Btw you can do something like this: `\newcommand{\o}{\operatorname{ord}}` and then just write `\o(\phi(1))` to get $\operatorname{ord}(\phi(1))$ and you only need to do it once, saves on a lot of typing. I'm not especially confident in group theory though, so I hope someone else confirms for you.

Comment: I think you need to be more careful about differentiating between the cyclic group $\langle\phi(1)\rangle$ and the element $\phi(1)$ of the group of order $24$. They are not the same thing. For example, you could say if $\phi(1)=a$ and $o(\phi(1))=n$ then $a^n=e$, so $\langle\phi(1)\rangle=\{e,a,a^2,\dots,a^{n-1}\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_n.$

Comment: Also $\{e\}\not\cong e$ since $\{e\}$ is the trivial subgroup and $e$ is just an element.